# Waffle-tomcat9 not working if files are not in the lib folder

Tags: tomcat, jar, config, tomcat9, waffle

I am trying to get this working without having to put he waffle-jna and waffle-tomcat9 in the lib folder.  If I manually put the jars in the tomcat lib folder everything loads up fine.  However, I would like to use the waffle jars files that are pulled down from Maven and not having to manually put them in the tomcat\lib folder.

Within my web app I have set in META-INF\context.xml the follwoing:

```
 <Valve className="waffle.apache.NegotiateAuthenticator" principalFormat="fqn" roleFormat="both"/> 
 <Realm className="waffle.apache.WindowsRealm"/>
```

If I remove the two files from the tomcat\lib folder I receive the following error:

```
 Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start.
 SEVERE: Begin event threw exception
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: waffle.apache.NegotiateAuthenticator
```

I found an article indicating to set loader delegate to true.  But this doesn't seem to work.

```
 <Loader delegate="true"/> in $(catalina.base)/conf/context.xml
```

What needs to be done to get tomcat to read the jars from the WEB-INF\lib folder?

I assume no one is doing this based on so many responses?